# "Using variable X before assignment" error pops up for no obvious reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I've read about this error, but the thing is that I do not think I should be getting this error here, and I've never seen anyone have this problem. Here is my code:

```
def substituie(caractere):
    lista_optiuni = genereaza_lista_substitutii(caractere)

    global sir
    sir = sterge_lambda(sir)
    while lista_optiuni != []:
        index = randrange(0,len(lista_optiuni))
        if len(sir) + len(lista_optiuni[index])-1 > 60:
             lista_optiuni.remove(lista_optiuni[index])
        else: 
             sir = sir.replace(caractere,lista_optiuni[index],1)
             sir = sterge_lambda(sir)
             return True
    return False
```

The problem is with my variable "Sir". I have an outside variable called "Sir" and I want my function to change certain aspects of it without passing it as a parameter. So I declare it as global inside the function, yet I still get an error as if my function has no idea who this variable is. Also, the code works fine and does exactly what I want it to do, but the red line below it and the "1 problem" warning in the Source Control tab really bothers me. This happened in more places in my code, for example:

```
global sir
sir = sir.replace(caractere,lista_optiuni[index],1)
```

This line of code also gave the same error in the same function but for some reason it no longer does, instead it focuses on the 3rd line of code from my function. Also, sterge_lambda(sir) simply replaces a certain caracter with '', not sure if a one line function is worth making, but whatever.

P.S.: The code is written in Python 3.7 inside VSCode.

Comment: Given the rules of [scope](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_scope_and_namespaces.html) in Python, by initializing `sir` outside (or 'above') your function, it should already be in scope and you should not be getting this error, even without the `global` declaration.

Comment: I read a bit about the scope rules, and about how to use a global variable and I am pretty sure I did it right, so I can see 2 different possibilities:
1) I am wrong somehow
2) The IntelliSense, Python Linter, Interpreter, or whatever is responsible for pointing out these "problems", is flagging that as a false positive.

Comment: Try removing the `global` declaration and see if the problem goes away

Comment: @DanielR.Livingston: no, without `global` the assignments would make it a local. It's just a pylint false positive here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default linter used by Visual Studio, `pylint`, is complaining because it hasn't found any code that would assign something to `sir` before `substituie()` is called and the expression `sterge_lambda(sir)` in the statement `sir = sterge_lambda(sir)` is run.

This could indicate a problem with your code, because there is no global name `sir` set anywhere by the time `subtituie()` really is executed, then you'd get a `NameError: name 'sir' is not defined` exception.

If you are sure that this will never happen in your project, you can tell `pylint` to ignore this specific issue by adding a `# pylint: disable=...` entry on the same line, where `...` is replaced with the error code that's visible in the dialog box when you hover over the red line:

```
sir = sterge_lambda(sir)  # pylint: disable=E0601
```

or you can use the symbolic name, for E0601 that's `used-before-assignment`:

```
sir = sterge_lambda(sir)  # pylint: disable=used-before-assignment
```

You can see the full list of message names and their error codes by running `pylint --list-msgs` on the command line, or you can access information on individual messages with `pylint --help-msg=<code-or-name>`.

Comment: I have tested the code so many times, it never failed because of not being assigned a value before calling. I even debugged and ran it step by step at least 10 times (for other reasons) and the string was always initialized on time. Does defining a function before a global variable being used inside it is declared and initialized cause a problem like that?

Comment: @AdrianBunea: it's just a false positive. pylint is not perfect, it doesn't run the code and can't work out every possible scenario. It can be wrong, and if you know it to be wrong, just disable the message for that one line.

Comment: @AdrianBunea: also, a linter is just a tool to help you write better code and to detect errors before they happen. The linter giving you a message here does not mean your code is actually broken, and linters don't catch every bug.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the order in which I define functions and declare global variables used inside said functions matter. While:

```
def substituie(caractere):
    lista_optiuni = genereaza_lista_substitutii(caractere)

    global sir
    sir = sterge_lambda(sir)
    while lista_optiuni != []:
       index = randrange(0,len(lista_optiuni))
       if len(sir) + len(lista_optiuni[index])-1 > 60:
           lista_optiuni.remove(lista_optiuni[index])
       else: 
           sir = sir.replace(caractere,lista_optiuni[index],1)
           sir = sterge_lambda(sir)
           return True
    return False

sir = start
```

would cause an error message to pop up, although the execution still proceeds normally, this code:

```
sir = start

def substituie(caractere):
    lista_optiuni = genereaza_lista_substitutii(caractere)

    global sir
    sir = sterge_lambda(sir)
    while lista_optiuni != []:
       index = randrange(0,len(lista_optiuni))
       if len(sir) + len(lista_optiuni[index])-1 > 60:
           lista_optiuni.remove(lista_optiuni[index])
       else: 
           sir = sir.replace(caractere,lista_optiuni[index],1)
           sir = sterge_lambda(sir)
           return True
    return False
```

does not complain about any problem. The only difference is that in the first version the variable used in the function is declared after the function definition. This is not an execution problem, just the way it is interpreted.

Comment: There's no problem with *either* code, as long as `sir = start` precedes the first *call* to `substituie`.

Comment: True, it is no problem, it executes perfectly. But pylint decided it doesn't like the first version and gave me a false positive.